# User-defined Controls and Their Properties

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I am working on a user-defined button, this has two custom properties like this:

```
public enum FirstType
{
    egg,
    leg
}
// first property:
public FirstType FirstProperty { get; set; }
```

and I have a base class and 5 derived classes of this base class, and the second property will refer to one of these 5,

```
//second property
public BaseClass SecondProperty { get; set; }
```

**Now my question is:** how can I have a drop down list of these 5 classes for the second property in `properties window` like the first one? Is it possible?

Comment: Just it is in gray and there are no default choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,I used `enum` to solve my problem, first a property of this enum type, then called those classes in `set` statement of the property. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

For that property you need to create your own custom `TypeConverter` and override `GetStandardValues`

This is your property:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyTypeConverter)]
public BaseClass SecondProperty { get; set; }
```

This is your type converter:

```
public class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    ...

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// select only from list
    /// </summary>
    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return new StandardValuesCollection(/* list of derived classes */);
    }
}
```